# how to detect if a number is between two other numbers in C?

Tags: c, loops

how do I detect if a user input int is between 2 numbers?

I've tried doing this:

```
int x=3;
printf("Enter the size of the triangle: ");
scanf("%d", &size);
odd=size%2;

for(x=3;x<21;x++)
{
  if(x==size&&odd==1)
  {
     break;
  }
  else
  {
 printf("The size must be an odd number and be between\n3 and 21, inclusive, please try again\n\n");
     printf("Enter the size of the triangle: ");
     scanf("%d",&size);
     odd=size%2;
     x=3;
  } 
}
```

But the only input I can use is 3.

Comment: BTW, if it's 3 through 21 inclusive, your `for` loop should be `<= 21`.

Answer (score 3):

You already have all the bits of the solution in the code:

```
if (size >= 3 && size <= 21) {
   // size is between 3 and 21 inclusive
} else {
   // size is less than 3 or more than 21
}
```

If you also want to ensure it's odd, you can add the condition:

```
if ((size >= 3) && (size <= 21) && (size % 2 == 1)) {
   // size is between 3 and 21 inclusive, and odd
} else {
   // size is less than 3 or more than 21 or even
}
```

Comment: but how will it repeat if it's less than 3 or more than 21 or even?

Comment: Inerdial, added the "odd" bit at the end to make the answer fit more closely the code, since I'm not a big fan of the `if (x%2)` way of doing things in the other answers. Hope you don't mind. If you do, you can revert and I'll take away my upvote :-) Just kidding.

Comment: @user1154601 To repeat, you can loop forever (using `while (1)`), or for some predetermined number of attempts (using a `for` loop), and `break` when the size is good. (Also kind of close to your original code.)

Answer (score 1):

If your need is to continuously ask the user for a number until they enter one that's:

- odd; and
- between 3 and 21 inclusive,

you can use something like:

```
printf ("Enter the size of the triangle: ");
scanf ("%d", &size);
while ((x < 3) || (x > 21) || (x % 2 == 0)) {
    printf ("The size must be an odd number and be between\n"
        "3 and 21, inclusive, please try again.\n\n");
    printf ("Enter the size of the triangle: ");
    scanf ("%d", &size);
}
```

This is probably the simplest form. It gets the number then enters the `while` loop until it's valid.

You *could* refactor the `printf/scanf` pair into a separate function but that's probably not so important in a small snippet like this.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if(x >= 3 && x <= 21 && x%2) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("Enter the size of the triangle");
scanf("%d", &size);

if (3 <= size && size <= 21 && size % 2) {
    // size is between 3 and 21 (inclusive) and odd
}
```